# How to consume WS (Http) + ClientCredentials.UserName

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
endP = new EndpointAddress("http:......");
WebPortClient client = new WebPortClient (binding, endP);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Pass";
```

The error is
Additional information: The server returned an invalid SOAP error. See InnerException for more information .

And my InnerException says:
{ " Start element ' faultcode ' namespace ' Line 1 was expected ." Element was found ' faultcode ' namespace ' http://schemas.oblix.com/ws/2003/08/Faults ' . , 172. " position }

what´s wrong?
Thank you